# Message controller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in iOS programming, I know this is too old question but I am confused here about message controller. I want to make a application in which I want to send simple messages. 
if I set multiple recipients can any of one can you view all recipients?
if it so,then how can I make a private message for all so that one recipient can't view other recipients?

Here is my code for composing a message for more recipients

```
- (void)showSMS:(NSString*)file {

    if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [warningAlert show];
        return;
    }

    NSArray *recipents = @[@"12345678", @"72345524"];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Just sent the %@ file to your email. Please check!", file];

    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [messageController setRecipients:recipents];
    [messageController setBody:message];
    [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried?  What happened?

Comment: i try too much but i found no solution. i say thanks i advance to the member who help me out of that problem

Comment: What I mean is, with your current code can recipient 1 see that the message was also sent to receipts to 2?  If so then you will,have to send multiple, individual messages. It may be that the in-built messaging support may not be right for your app. You may need to use a commercial service

Comment: @Paulw11 can you have any suggestion for tha

Comment: Twilio is one. There are others you can search

Comment: @Paulw11 i want to send a message to more the 1 recipients

Comment: @Paulw11 Twilio is third part API.  i want to use native controls

Comment: I understand that. What I am saying is that MFMessageComposeViewController Doesn't have 'bcc' so either all recipients will see other recipients, you need to send multiple individual messages or you need to use a service provider and not the native capability.

Comment: bcc is not in MFMessageComposeViewController and i want to send multiple individual message

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in Settings -> Messages which disables group messaging, and all recipients will receive the messages separately. Other than that, you can't do it with `MFMessageComposeViewController` because there's no bcc option. Your could send the messages one at a time though